# Method returning image visible on iPhone screen intermittently returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

It looks like I might've potentially found an answer to one of my earlier problems and would be happy to post the solution on SO though I first need to confirm it works properly.

The problem is it seems to be - most of the time, though not always. I've isolated the problematic code - it's a method I created whose purpose is to return a UIImage of what is currently visible on the device's screen. It looks like this:

```
+ (UIImage *)getImageVisibleOnScreenWith: (CGRect) boundingRect rotationAngle: (CGFloat) angle scalingRatio: (CGFloat) scale entireImageView: (UIImageView *) imageView actualVisibleView: (UIView *) visibleView {

    // Create a graphics context the size of the bounding rectangle
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(boundingRect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Rotate and translate the context
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, boundingRect.size.width/2, boundingRect.size.height/2);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, -scale);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    // Draw the image into the context
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-imageView.image.size.width/2, -imageView.image.size.height/2, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height), imageView.image.CGImage);

    // Get an image from the context
    UIImage *viewImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)];

    // Clean up
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Get the image currently on the screen (it's an intersection of specific UIImageViews)
    CGRect visibleImageRect = CGRectIntersection(imageView.frame, visibleView.frame);
    UIImage *visibleImage = (__bridge UIImage *)(CGImageCreateWithImageInRect((__bridge CGImageRef)(viewImage), visibleImageRect));

    return visibleImage;
}
```

I pass on the result of this method to another one and noticed it sometimes returns nil - for no apparent reason, well at least I couldn't find any.

As usual, any ideas and help will be appreciated; also let me know if you need to see more code or if there's anything unclear as to what the purpose it is.

Comment: Are you sure it's returning `nil` and the problem isn't that the variable you're stuffing the result in is getting released?

Comment: The way I check it is:

    UIImage *rotatedImage = [ImageManipulation getImageVisibleOnScreenWith:boundingRect rotationAngle:totalAngle scalingRatio:theScale entireImageView:self.photoView actualVisibleView:self.actualPhotoFrame];
      if (rotatedImage == nil) {
         NSLog(@"Was nil");
      }

What could be wrong with that? Why would the variable be getting released? I'm relatively new to objective-C development - hence the questions.

Comment: Since the declaration, allocation, and reference are all in the same code block, then it's not the problem. Try stepping through the code to see where it fails.